# Why do system administrators set the taskbar to not show the date and time on a server?

Tags: windows, configuration

What is the point in specifically setting the date time not to show? It's so annoying when you are RDP'ed to a server in full screen to figure out the time.

I'm not asking for a solution. I want to know the rationale in this setting in the first place.  Is it a security thing? What?

Comment: resources? I  have no idea... just type time at the cmd prompt I guess. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That option is not one that is set by a system administrator.  It is the default when you RDP into a domain-joined server.  You can find registry hacks to change this default here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/06df9377-9f58-4b39-a72f-9261ec2837ab